# Is it possible to configure nagios business process (nagiosbp) to use a tcp socket instead of a unix socket?

Tags: nagios, add-on

I'm looking to use NagiosBP nagios business process addon in conjunction with the NagVis addon.  My nagios server is remote and exporting nagios data via mklivestatus via a tcp port.

NagVis is easily configured to use the tcp socket, but NagiosBP appears to be only configurable to use a local unix socket.  Is there a way to configure NagiosBP to use the tcp socket ?

Answer (score 1):

ndodb.pm needs to be modified to allow use of the TCP socket e.g.

```
            my @livestatus = split(':',$dbparam{'ndo_livestatus_socket'});

            if ($livestatus[0] eq 'tcp') {
              $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new ("PeerHost" => $livestatus[1], "PeerPort" => $livestatus[2], "Proto" => $livestatus[0], "Type" => SOCK_STREAM, "Timeout" => 15) or die "unable to connect to tcp socket \"" . $dbparam{'ndo_livestatus_socket'} . "\": $!\n";
            } else {
              $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new ("Peer" => $dbparam{'ndo_livestatus_socket'}, "Type" => SOCK_STREAM, "Timeout" => 15) or die "unable to connect to unix socket \"" . $dbparam{'ndo_livestatus_socket'} . "\": $!\n";
            }
```

There are 3 places in the ndodb.pm file that need to be modified to enable this.